# Undefined reference to `WinMain@16' while compiling

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw, mingw32

I just installed *Visual Studio Code* and was trying to run my code when this came up:

> Undefined reference to `WinMain@16' while compiling

I searched through the web for a relevant answer, but none that I found worked.

Here is a more detailed **output** in the console:

```
cd "f:\" && g++ testing.cpp -o testing && "f:\"testing
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status,
```

By the way, I am using code-runner to run that single file. I have MinGW path all set up—though I don't know if that even matters.

[image: here is what it looks like]

Comment: I am not trying something very complex. Just a hello world program for now to test the proper working of the VS Code.

Comment: Did you configure the mingw environment correctly?

Answer (score 8):

The code runner does not save your code before running it. You can see the commands it executes in the error snippet you have added

```
cd "f:\" && g++ testing.cpp -o testing && "f:\"testing
```

So make sure you save your code before running it. This happened with me and I wasted quite some time.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and this worked for me: In Visual Studio Code, go to:

> *File* -> *Preferences* -> *Settings* -> *Run Code Configuration*

And check the *Save all files before run*.

Answer (score 2):

Save your single file and then it will compile successfully.

I had the same question as yours and I solved it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If it is cpp file, you should have a main function in your file to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using some library such as SDL2. The error is saying that it cannot find the entry point to your program.

> undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

That is because your library redefined what the entry point function is called.

Instead of using:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

you should use:

```cpp
int WinMain() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this should only be used for testing that everything is being included correctly. After you start actually using the library, it will probably have some `init` function that will call the `WinMain()` function for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to file>Autosave.
just click on autosave and it should solve your issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the end of your code:

```
int main(){}
```

The problem is solved :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to save the program before executing, as [@junpfeng noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59970389/3025856); that's the most probable problem.

If the problem still persists then that means your Mingw folder got corrupted and you need to reinstall it. It won't take long, just 3-4 minutes max.

In case you want the link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/

***P.S.,*** try clearing the path again in the environment variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).