# how to fix vs code installation issue?

Tags: installation

i cant use vs code terminal and this pops up
S C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\c++ project> cd "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\c++ project" ; if ($?) { g++ newpro.cpp -o newpro } ; if ($?) { .\newpro }
c:/users/admin/desktop/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
i dont even knows what that means. i did everything step by step as guy in the yt told me. its 5th time already. im tired boss..

i tried to run code? idk what am i suppose to leave here.

Comment: see: [Undefined reference to \`WinMain@16' while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035451/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-while-compiling)